Benji Gregory, star of ALF, has passed
Benji Gregory Hertzberg, who played Brian Tanner in ALF, has died, found dead in his car along with his service dog, apparently from heat stroke, on June 13th.

Gregory portrayed Brian on all four seasons of the classic sitcom. Before this breakthrough role, he appeared on episodes of shows such as "The A-Team," "Punky Brewster" and "The Twilight Zone."

